# AAD / ADAL: understanding user authorisation of app and "Show details" link

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I'm working on a proof of concept with Azure Active Directory and a native client obtaining an OpenID token for authentication to a web app. The native client uses `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync`. My native client app is called "*Proof of concept*" and the web app is called "*PoC server*".

The first time that a user logs in, the embedded browser opened by ADAL requires the user to authorise the application, with this page:

[image: Screenshot]

Translation:

> Authorise Proof of concept
>
> Proof of concept
>   Website of the application's publisher: nathexperimental.onmicrosoft.com
>
> Proof of concept needs permission to
>
> - Access PoC server (PoC server)
> - Log in and read your profile
>
> You've logged in as: test2@nathexperimental.onmicrosoft.com
>
> Show details
>
> [Accept] [Cancel]

If I now click on the "Show details" link, it throws an exception:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: Non-HTTPS url redirect is not supported in webview
   en Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenInteractiveHandler.VerifyAuthorizationResult()
   en Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenInteractiveHandler.<PreTokenRequest>d__8.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   en Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<RunAsync>d__55.MoveNext()
```

I'm not sure what the non-HTTPS URL it's trying to redirect to is, but my best guess is that it's the redirection URI of the native client, which I had set to `hook://login` with the intention to implement a custom protocol handler and see what calls were made.

This seems to be confirmed by the fact that when I changed the redirection URI to `https://codegolf.stackexchange.com` (it was the first HTTPS-enabled site that came to mind...), the behaviour changed. But not in the way I expected. Now when I log in for the first time as a new user, it skips the entire "Authorise Proof of concept" page.

What's going on? Under what conditions is the user required to authorise the application? Does the scenario where they must authorise permit me to supply a "More details" page?

Comment: Strange! I'll get someone to look into the exception. For a multi-tenant app using the `/common` endpoint, you should see the "authorise" (aka consent) screen if the user/tenant has not previously consented to the app.  It shouldn't have any relationship to the `redirect_uri` used. I suspect that some other error is being returned before Azure AD tries to show the consent screen.

Comment: @dstrockis, I'm not using the `/common` endpoint (or, at least, not intentionally). I'm passing my native client app's client ID. If you want I can post some verbose logging output tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript code in the Trident webview is getting accounted as non https url in ADAL. The issue has been filed and the commit is under review for Adal.NET.
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/544